# How to add API permissions to an application registration using either Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-service-principal, azure-app-registration, microsoft-entra-id

Attempting to assign a role to an app registration but struggling to identify the suitable command in the AZ module for PowerShell or Azure CLI.

The [AzureAD Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) command below is functioning as intended:

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $resourceObjectId -Id $roleId -PrincipalId $sourceServicePrincipalId -ResourceId $resourceObjectId
```

However, I'm encountering difficulties migrating the above-mentioned command to a new module. I'm uncertain about which scope to specify for the new commands, leading to issues in the migration process.

Kindly someone help here

I Need help to Migrate above command to Azure CLI / AZ module powershell script.

Comment: For Az Cli, did you check the `az ad` commands? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: `az ad app permission` seems to do the job: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-permission-add

Comment: Hi @Thomas
I am trying to add an API permission to an application registration, to request for static consent
Gone through above two links but getting error message as "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Comment: you need to be "app admin" in MS entra ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created one **App role** named **`tasks.read`**  with below properties:

[image]

Now, I ran below **`Az`** PowerShell command to assign this **App role** API permission to an application registration:

```
Add-AzADAppPermission -ApplicationId $sourceAppId -ApiId $resourceappId -PermissionId $roleId -Type Role
Get-AzADAppPermission -ApplicationId $sourceAppId
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **API permission** added successfully under app registration like this:

[image]

To do the same via Azure CLI, you can make use of below command:

```bash
az ad app permission add --id <sourceAppObjId> --api <resourceAppId> --api-permissions <roleId>=Role --only-show-errors
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you are getting *"Insufficient privileges"* error, make sure to assign at least **Application Administrator** Entra role to your user under directory like this:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Roles and administrators -> All roles -> Select role -> Add assignment*

[image]

**Reference:**

[Add-AzADAppPermission (Az.Resources) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/add-azadapppermission?view=azps-11.1.0)